# How to display to terminal in SQLPLUS the column of a row with the width of the max value of the data within that column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I was wondering if this could be done without the COLUMN FORMAT.

Current example:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                BIG DATAFILE_NAME
------------------------------ --- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
STORETABS                      NO  C:\ORACLE\APP\ASUH\ORADATA\TESTORCL\STORETABS_01.DBF
STORETABS                      NO  C:\ORACLE\APP\ASUH\ORADATA\TESTORCL\STORETABS_02.DBF
```

Notice the header "-" lines are extended all the way out to match the varchar(n) value defined.

Is there a SQLPLUS SET command that will auto adjust the column width to either the size of the column header or the size of the max data within the column?

I want it to look like this:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME  BIG DATAFILE_NAME
---------------- --- -----------------------------------------------------
STORETABS        NO  C:\ORACLE\APP\ASUH\ORADATA\TESTORCL\STORETABS_01.DBF
STORETABS        NO  C:\ORACLE\APP\ASUH\ORADATA\TESTORCL\STORETABS_02.DBF
```

If not by the size of the column header, adjusting to the max size of the data is more desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such setting.

There can't be such a setting, because `SQL*Plus` fetches *arraysize* (default of which is 15, I believe) records at a time. So, if after 15 records another longer record is fetched, the `-------....` is already printed/written, leaving no chance to SQL*Plus to adjust it.

*arraysize* is the number set with `set arraysize n`.